# How to get the event info in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-devtools

I'm trying to use Vue Devtools to debug my App and I was wondering how to retrieve the info I see after an event.

```
   <l-marker v-for="marker in markers" 
     :lat-lng="marker.position"
     :key="marker.id" 
     :draggable=true 
     @dragend="dragend">
  </l-marker>
```

My event is **@dragend**="dragend",How can I get the **lat** and **lng** values?

### [image]

**Edit:** Is this correct?

```
 dragend: function(event){

            console.log(event.target._latlng);
 }
```

Comment: if you edit your attribute in`:lat-lng.sync="marker.position"` you will have the position always updated within the property `marker.position`, without using `@dragend`

Comment: Thanks a lot @fabruex!  .sync is very helpful! I'll use it to update render and @dragend to call a method and apply search in bg. very helpful! Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I added it as answer

Comment: Allora grazie ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you edit your attribute in

```
:lat-lng.sync="marker.position"
```

you will have the position always updated within the property `marker.position`, without using `@dragend` event